# How to switch Mac terminal's python3 from 3.8.x to 3.7.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, terminal, pyenv

I'm trying to change my mac's python3 from 3.8.12 to 3.7.12

Currently, I have python 2.7.16, 3.9.4 , 3.8.12, and 3.7.12 installed on my mac. My default python is using 2.7.16 (`python -V` shows 2.7.16), and my python3 is using 3.8.12 (`python3 -V` shows 3.8.12)

For some reason, I want to use 3.7.12 as my python3. I tried managing the python version by using pyenv. But after I using `pyenv global 3.7.12`, the `pyenv versions` shows that 3.7.12 was set, but when I type `python3 -V`, it still shows 3.8.12

What should I do to change the version of my Mac's python3?

Comment: Personally, I use Nix for this, and strongly recommend it -- unlike pyenv (which is only good for Python), you can use Nix to manage versions of any software you want (Node, Ruby, native-compiled C applications, etc etc). See https://nixos.org/ -- while NixOS is a full Linux distro, Nix itself works on other operating systems, including MacOS.

Comment: This can be very frustrating.  What I've done is created `~/bin/python3` as a symlink to the executable I want.

Comment: Just prepend the path to your desired executable to `$PATH` in your `.bash_profile`

Comment: Everybody has a point. I just want to add conda/anaconda in the list.